# Подключение PHP к apache

Tags: apache, php

Уважаемые, подскажите. Как подключить php к apache как модуль. Раньше удавалось, сейчас - нет. Видимо забыл. Помню как-то... LoadModule... php5_module... Точно что-то напутал...

Comment: http://www.opennet.ru/base/sec/mod_security_slack.txt.html

Вот пример как можно подключать разные модулю

Comment: Скажу честно, у меня никогда не получалось так ставить, всегда использовал xampp, только удалял в нём mysql и ставил свою, всё ок, советую.

Answer (score 2):

```
apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5 libapache2-mod-ruby php5 php5-common php5-curl php5-dev php5-gd php5-idn php-pear php5-imagick php5-imap php5-mcrypt php5-memcache php5-mhash php5-ming php5-mysql php5-pspell php5-recode php5-snmp php5-sqlite php5-tidy php5-xmlrpc php5-xsl
```

А вообще нужно уточнять под какую ос ставим!

Answer (score 2):

[Установка Apache + Mysql + Php](http://www.php.ru/install). В ReadME php всегда есть инструкция.